# Is Java File object from a MultipartRequest written to disk as temp file or stored in memory?

Tags: java, servlets

If I accept a file from a MultipartRequest and call

```
File f = request.getFile("fileName");
```

Is the file written to disk (as a temp file) or is it only stored in memory at this point?

Comment: What `MultipartRequest` are you talking about? Spring?

Comment: com.oreilly.servlet.MultipartRequest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about the o'Reilly [MultipartRequest](http://www.stanford.edu/group/coursework/docsTech/oreilly/com.oreilly.servlet.MultipartRequest.html) it'll always be written to disk according to the link.

---

Update
If you're talking about the [Spring commons FileUpload](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/multipart/commons/CommonsFileUploadSupport.html#setMaxInMemorySize%28int%29) component, it does support this setup. One of the properties you can set is `setMaxInMemorySize(int bytes)` which determines the max size of a file that will be held in memory and not written to disk.

Comment: Thanks, reading the documentation on the link you provided for o'Reilly clearly states that getFile(String s) "Returns a File object for the specified file saved on the server's filesystem, or null if the file was not included in the upload."

Comment: You're right, despite providing the link I misread the constructor docs! Updated.

Answer (score 0):

This is implementation dependent.  You have no need to know, short of wanting to short-circuit an operation like "move."  But even the *File* object returned could be an implementation-dependent interface that supports move semantics from memory to disk.